# 120/240 home generator interlock/transfer outlet/adapter setup

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator

So I'm wondering what sort of inlet / adapters I need to accomplish the following.

Suppose I own the following generators:
Honda EU2200: 2x 120V-15A (Standard home outlets)
Honda EU2200 Companion: 1x 30A 125V Locking Plug (NMEA L5-30), 1x 120V-15A
Honda EU7000: 30A 125/250V Locking Plug (NMEA L14-30)

What I'd like to do is setup an inlet and cables so I can use any of the above combinations. (I'm aware I can't power any 240V devices w/ the 2200/2200 companions. Also I have the manual transfer switch installed already that disables the main before allowing the generator breakers to turn on.)

My guess is the following:
In the wall, install a NMEA L14-30R inlet and wire it to both sides of the panel. This will naturally fit the EU7000 in 250V mode.

What I'm less sure about is this:
For the 2200 companion: Order a cable that uses a NMEA L5-30P (to plug into 2200 companion) w/ a L14-30R (To plug into the above wall inlet). It would bridge the single hot on the L5-30 to both hots on the 14-30. Like this, I think: [https://www.amazon.com/Generator-adapter-L14-30-female-voltage/dp/B07GMVJV7X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GMVJV7X)

For the 2200 solo: 5-15P Male to L5-30R Female adapter, to plug into the above adapter... (I realize this is bad form)

Does this all make sense? I think its right but would love someone who is more familiar to confirm. Thank you!

Comment: You may be just using the wrong words but just in case: DO NOT USE AN OUTLET! What you want is an INLET (with pins sticking out, not slots for pins). Using an outlet requires building a suicide cord with a pug on both ends! This is one of the nest ways to kill yourself or a loved one!

Comment: You are indeed correct! Let me edit, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you can not power 240v devices with the 2 connected? I set a friends travel trailer with the 2 units about a year ago and believe they had a true 30 amp 240v output. The generators sync the waveforms.  the commercial cable was a bit of a ripoff but I built a cable to go to his 240v inlet on his trailer. He bolted the generators in the bed of his truck so they would not get stolen. I would set up a home with the same setup 4 wire 30 amp 250v inlet into the home into a interlocked 30 amp breaker.  The output of the generator on a mating female receptacle to the inlet.

Comment: Couldn't you arrange all the loads you would use with the small generator onto one side of the panel?  In theory you could put them all on a single 15A breaker.  I assume for convenience you'll want to power things on various breakers but you don't get that much, can't they all be on one side?

Comment: I could, but the panel is already wired and I'd rather not have to re-wire and commit to what I want to use. Would like the flexibility to use anything if needed.

Comment: With the two panel phases bridged together in the inlet you would need to mark for non-use, not just the 240V circuits but also any MWBC circuits.  Admittedly with the 2200s you don't strictly need to do that but once you have a cable and a habit of operating this way, it would be useful to have the procedure in place to not fry an MWBC neutral if you ever use a larger generator this way.

Comment: Yes, we need to know about any MWBC before we could advise splitting 120V like that.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to simply use the EU7000 whenever you want to power the house? What loads do you want to run on generator power, for that matter?

Comment: I'd primarily use the EU7000 but want the option to user either the 2200 companion or solo if for some reason the EU7000 wasn't working...

Comment: It is a new build, so I'm assuming its not MWBC but not sure how to verify, haven't looked that deep at that yet...

Comment: @opsguy -- what are you wanting to power from the generator?

Comment: Worst case the biggest load would be our 240VA/C. I’d need one of those soft start kits. Besides that just the general house items, nothing too fancy.

Comment: @opsguy -- are you on city water/sewer, or well/septic?